# Why do i get different results from two servers that located in the same destination network?

Tags: networking, ping, isp, traceroute

There's two servers with the same network IP, and the only difference between them is the last two numbers like: `xx.xx.15.247` and `xx.xx.66.178`

When i try the command `Tracert` (Traceroute) to test the ping and to see what hops does it take to reach the destination server, i get different ping times and different forward path results which is strange because they are all located in the same company host.

Is there something wrong? Shouldn't it take the same path too?